# Java サイコロゲーム　引き分け判定の方法を教えてください。

Tags: java

サイコロを振って、合計値が高い人の勝ち。というゲームをEclipseを用いて作成しています。

ルールとしては以下の流れになります。

1. プレイヤーは3人
2. 3回ずつサイコロを振り、各プレイヤーの合計値を出す
3. 合計値が一番高い人の勝ち（引き分けの場合は引き分けとする）

しかし、引き分け判定の記載方法がわかりません。
アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

**現在のコード:**

```
package test;

public class SaikoroGames {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 各プレイヤーの合計値を代入
    int hokan[] = new int[3];
    
    // プレイヤー人数を決める
    int player = 3;
    int sum = 0;
    int dice = 0;
    
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // 人数分ループする
    for (int j = 0; j < player; j++) {
        System.out.printf("[%d] : ", j + 1);
      sum = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= player; i++) {
        dice = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
        System.out.print(dice + " ");
        sum += dice;
        
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("合計値 :" + sum);
      max = Math.max(max, sum);
      hokan[j] = sum;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
    }
    // 勝者判定
    for (int j = 0; j < player; j++) {
      if (hokan[j] == max) {
          System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("勝者は[%d]、" , j + 1);
        System.out.print("合計値は" + hokan[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

最大値を獲得したプレーヤ(複数人の可能性あり)を先に抽出しておいて、
後でそれらをまとめて出力する、という流れで処理するのはどうでしょうか。

```java
// 勝者判定
// 最大値(max)を獲得したプレーヤをピックアップ
List<Integer> winners = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < player; j++) {
    if (hokan[j] == max) {
        winners.add(j);
    }
}
// maxを獲得したプレーヤとmax値を出力
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("勝者は");
for (int winner : winners) {
    System.out.printf("[%d]", winner + 1);
}
// maxを獲得したプレーヤが2人以上なら引き分け
if (winners.size() >= 2) {
    System.out.print("(引き分け)");
}
System.out.print("、合計値は" + max);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 参考にさせていただきます！